# Angular one time binding fails to wait for a boolean condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, binding

**The problem:**

Using angularjs 1.3.0 beta 15, I'm trying to "bindonce" to a property of an object that is fetched from a server:

```
<div ng-if="::(myObject.foo === 'bar')"></div>
```

if `myObject` is not yet fetched (its promise is not resolved) in the time this html is loaded, angular evaluates the expression as false (no matter the value of course), and stops watching it.

**Possible workarounds that I'd rather avoid:**

- Removing the `::` solves this of course - not an option (performance-wise)
- replacing `foo` with `isFooEqualsBar`, that gets its value when `myObject` is resolved (and binding to `::isFooEqualsBar`) - it requires a lot of new properties just for that
- Return to the stable 1.2 version, and use bindonce

Is it a bug? or am I using the `::` syntax wrong?

Comment: whenever your expression will get value other than undefined, it will be evaluated. So instead of false set expression to undefined. So next time, it will be evaluated when a resolve set some data in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable,
>   which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a
>   non-undefined value (see value stabilization algorithm below).

I think the problem is that your expression is false after the first digest.

```
undefined === 'bar' is false.
```

Maybe something like

```
<div ng-if="::(myObject.foo ? myObject.foo === 'bar' : undefined)"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's essentially the second workaround, only inlined. Hoping for something more concise...

Comment: This should also work too: ng-if="::(myObject.foo && myObject.foo === 'bar')"

Comment: You can also write a function: $scope.uc = function(a,b) { return a ? a===b : undefined }, and use that generically.   <div ng-if="uc(myObject.foo,'bar')"></div>